# Finding $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n 2^k \tan^{-1}(k)+3^k }{\sum_{k=1}^n 3^k\tan^{-1}(k)}=\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n 2^k \tan^{-1}(k)+3^k }{\sum_{k=1}^n 3^k\tan^{-1}(k)}=\alpha$$ then what will be the value of $\alpha\pi?$

This is a question from a university entrance exam. I don't understand are they missing limit or is the question correct.

I was thinking of converting it to limit of sum but I don't think it is working. Any hint rather than the complete answer would be helpful

Comment: Why would you expect a limit? The value is a function of $n,$ presumably.

Comment: How do I approach the problem then?

Comment: Don't know, but I don't see how to approach it if we add a limit, either.

Comment: Because $\arctan(x) \sim \pi/2$ as $n$ gets...not even large, $15$ or more... you might calculate the expression in the limit, then see what you can do with those arctans working backward? I wonder if it's possible to switch the arctans to integrals $(\arctan x = \int_0^x dx/(x^2+1) = \int_0^1 xdt/(t^2x^2+1))$, and exchange the sum and integral... but I don't know for sure if that will work, or if the series coverages, etc...